# Jest test failing for MUI Select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I've been trying to write a Jest unit test for a MUI select component in a react and typescript application but my test seems unable to find the listbox I'm trying to test. All the approaches I've learned haven't worked and I can't seem to find an up to date answer on how to test this MUI select.

I've tried the following means of finding the selector: `screen.getByLabelText`, `screen.getByRole` and `screen.getByTestId`

I've tried finding the select component by searching for the select label, a test-id placed on the Select component as well as passing a test-id to the input props. The strange thing is these test IDs show up in the console for the failed test so I'm not sure why it's returning that it cannot find the element I'm trying to test.

Update: Resolved the above issue by passing a data-testid to the child input via inputprops. However, the latter part of my test is still failing with the .not.toBeNull() for some reason my child LeaveComponentModal is still seemingly null even though after the select is changed a secondary time it should be shown.

**My current test is:**

```
it("selects the timer option then changes the selection to communication and show confirm change modal popup", () => {
        render(<ActionsDrawer isActionDrawerOpen={isActionDrawerOpen} onClose={onClose} handleActionSubmit={handleActionSubmit} />);

        const actionOriginSelect = screen.getByTestId("actionOrigin");
        expect(actionOriginSelect).toBeInTheDocument();
        act(() => {
            fireEvent.change(actionOriginSelect, { target: { value: strategyActions.timer.value } });
        });
        const changeOriginModal = screen.queryByText("StrategyManager.Confirm_Change_Origin");
        expect(changeOriginModal).not.toBeInTheDocument();

        fireEvent.change(actionOriginSelect, { target: { value: strategyActions.communications.value } });
        expect(changeOriginModal).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

**The component that I'm trying to test:**

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">{t("StrategyManager.Select_Action_Origin")}</InputLabel>
        <Select
        name="actionOrigin"
        label="Select Action Origin"
        id="operator-select"
        value={formik.values.actionOrigin}
        onChange={(event) => handleFormDataChange(event)}
        fullWidth
        inputProps={{
            id: "actionOrigin",
            "data-testid": "actionOrigin"
        }}
    >
<MenuItem value={strategyActions.communications.value}>{t(strategyActions.communications.label)}</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={strategyActions.scoot.value}>{t(strategyActions.scoot.label)}</MenuItem>
<MenuItem data-testid="timer" value={strategyActions.timer.value}>{t(strategyActions.timer.label)}</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={strategyActions.socials.value}>{t(strategyActions.socials.label)}</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={strategyActions.vms.value}>{t(strategyActions.vms.label)}</MenuItem>
</Select>
</FormControl>
```

This select component calls the following method which effectively checks if a value has previously been selected, if it has a popup is shown to confirm a user wants to change their selection through a child LeaveComponentModal:

```
const handleFormDataChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
        if (formik.values.actionOrigin !== "") {
            setModalMessage("StrategyManager.Confirm_Change_Origin");
            setIsChangeModalOpen(true);
            return;
        } else {
            formik.handleChange(event);
        }
    };
```

**LeaveComponentModal:**

```
<LeaveConfirmationModal
                open={isChangeModalOpen}
                onClose={handleCloseModal}
                onConfirm={handleConfirmChangeDataOrigin}
                onCancel={handleCancel}
                message={message}
            />
```

I basically want to simulate a user clicking on the select box, getting the dropdown and then selecting an option from the list. Ideally I'd also like to mock the formik instance I've created to manage the form to check that once a user has made a selection the necessary field has been updated, in this case the `actionOrigin` field.

I'm also getting this console error regarding needing to wrap in an act() statement despite I believe having placed it in the correct location?
[image]

Comment: `"test-id" !== "data-testid"`

Comment: This helped! I found I could pass data-testid to the input props which then allowed my test to find the input and fire a change event against it and just set a specific target value rather than trying to mock a user selecting one instead!